# unwanted header file WinGDI.h

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I am doing some macros like

```
#define report_msg(type,msg_str).......my_special_##type(......)

#define report_error(msg_str) report_msg(ERROR,msg_str)
```

It works perfect under linux while when I compile with visual studio 2010 express, I see it gives error that

```
error C3861: 'my_special_0': identifier not found
```

The reason is that "ERROR" is interpreted as 0. And when I use "Go to defination" in MSVC, it goes to WinGDI.h

```
/* Region Flags */
#define ERROR 0
```

Question is why this WinGDI.h is  included? How can I eliminated it without touching the code?

Comment: We can't see your #includes.  Whatever they are, the order is wrong :)  Diagnose with /showIncludes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is why macros are evil. I've seen cases where TRUE and FALSE are defined with different values in different headers. In any project of decent size it may become tedious to follow the chains of headers. Try

```
#undef ERROR 

#define report_msg(type,msg_str).......my_special_##type(......)
#define report_error(msg_str) report_msg(ERROR,msg_str)
```

and hope that the "real" definition of ERROR is not needed after these statements.

Answer (score 12):

**Solution 1:**
Swap include orders of some headers -> tedious task

**Solution 2:**
Put `NOGDI` in preprocessor. In Visual Studio: Project Properties -> Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Preprocessor -> Preprocessor Definitions -> add `NOGDI`.

**Explanation:**
Paul pointed me in the right direction. I don't use precompiled headers, so I don't include `stdafx.h`. My problem is related to Linux vs. Windows libraries.

In my case I use a library, which defines the constant 'ERROR' for log messages. For timestamps `ctime.h` is included, which uses `Windows.h`/`WinGDI.h`.

Comment: `/DNOGDI` for the win! You just saved me days of refactoring to remove variables with the name `ERROR` out of our codebase lol (Not defending `ERROR` as a good choice of variable name)

Answer (score 1):

`WinGDI.h` is probably included via `Windows.h` from your `stdafx.h`. To be sure where it is included from enable "Show includes" option here: Project settings->Configuration Properties->C/C++->Advanced->Show Includes->Yes and recompile your source.