# Rewrite ERROR constant in C++

Tags: c++

When trying to compile the following C++ code snippet (using Microsoft Visual Studio 2015):

```
namespace NS
{
    const int ERROR = -1;
};
```

It returns the following error:

```
c:\workspace\X.hpp(141): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before 'constant'
c:\workspace\X.hpp(141): error C2059: syntax error: 'constant'
```

The constant ERROR is already defined somewhere, since if one makes the line a comment, ERROR can still be printed (it returns 0 for that matter).

I thought this type of collision could be avoid by defining a namespace.

How can one defined his/her own constant ERROR?

Comment: `#define ERROR ...` most likely.

Comment: Are you sure this is the exact code? Your compiler is complaining about `constant` which is not a keyword in C++ (and also doesn't appear in your code snippet)

Comment: Names that are all uppercase are normally macros, not normal variables or functions. You can't redefine a macro in a namespace.

Comment: If I change `const int ERROR = -1;` to let's say `const int ERRORX = -1;` it works perfectly, so the issue is that it seems that I am overwriting something already predefined.

Comment: Visual Studio has an option to show preprocessed output. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z9z0bx6.aspx. Try that and see if `ERROR` is being defined as macro somewhere.

Comment: in wingdi.h, line 114 : #define ERROR 0

Comment: Ok, so it's defined in file wingdi.h. How can one rewrite his/her own `ERROR` constant through a namespace?

Comment: @user5793565 : Nope, you can't. A constant is evaluated before any compilation of your code. So your code snippet will be interpreted as `const int 0 = -1;` even in a namespace.

Comment: @user - The problem is that macros don't respect namespaces.

Comment: Um, can't rewrite?   Perhaps insert an "#undef ERROR" prior to your use of the ERROR symbol for the const int.   Also, you might try an enum inside your class or namespace

Comment: I think you can find the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27064391/unwanted-header-file-wingdi-h